# How to add multiple CASE Statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN (LEFT(`Data`,2))=10 THEN  'Barang 1'
WHEN (LEFT(`Data`,2))=20 THEN  'Barang 2'
WHEN (LEFT(`Data`,2))=30 THEN  'Barang 3'
WHEN (LEFT(`Data`,2))=40 THEN  'Barang 4'
WHEN (LEFT(`Data`,2))=50 THEN  'Barang 5'
ELSE 'none'
END AS `ProdName`

CASE
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=01 THEN 'Januari'
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=02 THEN 'Februari'
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=03 THEN 'Maret'
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=04 THEN 'April'
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=05 THEN 'Mei'
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=06 THEN 'Juni'
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=07 THEN 'Juli'
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=08 THEN 'Agustus'
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=09 THEN 'September'
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=10 THEN 'Oktober'
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=11 THEN 'November'
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=12 THEN 'Desember'
ELSE 'none'
END AS `ProdTime`

FROM `LOGGING BARCODE`
```

i got errors:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that      corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=01 THEN 'Januari' WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=02 THEN 'Fe' at line 11

i need to parse `Data` but error occurs
thanks for helps

Comment: You forgot to add a comma. It should be END AS `ProdName`,

Comment: Oh ,i get it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add Parenthesis ()
**(**CASE
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=01 THEN 'Januari'
END**)** AS `ProdTime`,
**(**CASE
WHEN (MID(`Data`,3,2))=01 THEN 'Januari'
END**)** AS `ProdTime`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29847342)